# How to convert text type Duration data to time data format in Excel?

Tags: excel, data-analysis

I'm trying to do some analysis on the open-data of UFO sightings. I've collected the data from [National UFO Reporting Center.](http://www.nuforc.org/webreports/ndxe201509.html)

And the data looks like follows:

```
Date / Time     City    State   Shape   Duration    Summary     Posted
9/29/15 04:00   Wheaton     IL  Unknown     3 minutes   Object hovering for 1 minute, brightly lite and loud. Then moved past slowly. I called FAA to see if they knew what it was, they transf     9/29/15
9/28/15 23:17   Hendersom   NV  Triangle    ~1 minute   V-shape/triangle UFO sighting in Henderson and Las Vegas, NV.   9/29/15
9/28/15 22:08   Dousman     WI  Fireball    5 minutes   Bright yellowish/white light hovering, no sound of craft.   9/29/15
9/28/15 21:10   Tacna   AZ  Triangle    ~15 seconds     Brightly lit craft flew and hovered right in front of us, then disappeared.     9/29/15
9/28/15 20:35   York    ME  Triangle    10 minutes  Triangle bright flashing white light, releasing a red and white pattern craft heading straight up.  9/29/15
```

There are hundreds of records and now I'm facing a problem in reading the Duration column's data as it was written in simple text. I want it to be a number representing Time (3 minutes as 3, 30 seconds as 0.5, and etc). I want to automate the process of converting the column into actual time duration.

How to do that in Excel?? (or maybe even in R??)

Comment: Do any of the times have compound components, for example, `5 minutes and 30 seconds` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the Duration data are in column E, try this formula in a blank cell in row 2:

```
=MID(SUBSTITUTE(E2,"~",""),1,2)/IFERROR(IF(FIND("seconds",E2),60),1)
```

Now copy down as far as you need.

Note: this formula assumes there are no compound times and that the only units of time used are minutes and seconds; it makes no provision for hours. If you need hours, please let me know.

Comment: The data doesn't exactly have compound values but they do have some real vague representation of duration saying: `long, 2 hours +, 15-30 seconds, still up there, < 1 minute`. I'm trying to do data preprocessing on this, so you can also please provide me some ideas there.

Comment: Can you send me a sample workbook with all of the various duration values? I'll enhance the formula for you to cover them all if I can. My email address is:  daniel.ferry@gmail.com